# Como hago para que no me pida 2 veces el scanner?

Tags: java, bucles, eventos, scanner

Tengo un programa con java beans y necesito que me pida una vez el hierro pero si la diferencia es mayor de 10 entre el hierro inicial con el nuevohierro que se ha introducido salta un mensaje diciendo que debo de hacerme de nuevo la revision. Pues ahi es donde yo quiero el bucle para que pide todo el rato lo mismo. En caso de que la diferencia no sea mayor de 10 se acaba el programa

main

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int cantHierro = 10;
            int nuevaHierro;
   
 Paciente paciente1 = new Paciente ("Francisco", "Fuertes", 20, 123456789, 10, 20);
 GeneraAnalisis analisis1 = new GeneraAnalisis();
 analisis1.setProducto(paciente1);

  System.out.print("Cantidad de hierro: ");
    cantHierro = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Nueva cantidad de hierro: ");
        nuevaHierro = scan.nextInt();
        paciente1.setUltimoHierro(nuevaHierro);
        paciente1.addPropertyChangeListener(analisis1);
 
     do{
         
         System.out.println("Vuelva a introducir la cantidad de hierro");
         if((nuevaHierro - cantHierro) >10){
             System.out.print("Nueva cantidad de hierro: ");
        nuevaHierro = scan.nextInt();
        paciente1.setUltimoHierro(nuevaHierro);
         }

     }while((nuevaHierro - cantHierro) > 10);
    
 paciente1.addPropertyChangeListener(analisis1);
```

clase paciente

```
public class Paciente implements Serializable {


private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private int edad;
private int telefono;
private int ultimoHierro;
private int ultimaUrea;

private PropertyChangeSupport propertySupport;

public Paciente() {
    propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
}

public Paciente(String nombre, String apellidos , int edad, int telefono, int ultimoHierro, int ultimaUrea) {
    
    propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
   this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.ultimoHierro = ultimoHierro;
    this.ultimaUrea = ultimaUrea;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String descripcion) {
    this.nombre = descripcion;
}

public String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos;
}

public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int valorNuevo) {
   this.edad = edad;

}

public int getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void getTelefono(int telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public int getUltimoHierro() {
    return ultimoHierro;
}

public void setUltimoHierro(int hierroNuevo) {
     int hierroAnterior = this.ultimoHierro;
    this.ultimoHierro = hierroNuevo;

    
        if ((hierroNuevo - hierroAnterior) > 10) //hay que realizar pedido
    {
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange("Hierro actual",
                hierroAnterior, this.ultimoHierro);
        //dejamos el stock anterior, no actualizamos
        this.ultimoHierro = hierroAnterior;

    }else{
        System.out.println("Estas sano sanete");
    }
    
    
}

public int getUltimaUrea() {
    return ultimaUrea;
}

public void setUltimaUrea(int ultimaUrea) {
    this.ultimaUrea = ultimaUrea;
}



public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener 
listener) {
    propertySupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    propertySupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

}
```

clase generaAnalisis

```
public class GeneraAnalisis implements Serializable, PropertyChangeListener {

private int numAnalisis;
private Paciente paciente;
private Date fecha;
private int analisisPendiente;


public GeneraAnalisis() {

}

public GeneraAnalisis(int numeropedido, Paciente producto,
        Date fecha, int cantidad) {
    this.numAnalisis = numeropedido;
    this.paciente = producto;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.analisisPendiente = cantidad;
}

public int getNumeropedido() {
    return numAnalisis;
}

public void setNumeropedido(int numeropedido) {
    this.numAnalisis = numeropedido;
}

public Paciente getProducto() {
    return this.paciente;
}

public void setProducto(Paciente producto) {
    this.paciente = producto;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public int getCantidad() {
    return analisisPendiente;
}

public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.analisisPendiente = cantidad;
}

public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    System.out.printf("Hierro anterior: %d%n", evt.getOldValue());
    System.out.printf("Hierro Actual: %d%n", evt.getNewValue());

    System.out.printf("Realizar Analisis en paciente urgentemente:%s%n",
            paciente.getNombre() + " " + paciente.getApellidos());

    //insertar pedido  en la tabla               
    // BaseDatos.insertaPedido(producto, cantidad);        
}

}
```

en la consola me pide dos veces seguidas el nuevo hierro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero claro, si inicio el bucle sin haberle dado valores a la variable me da error. sugerencias?

Comment: El bucle do-while te garantiza que se ejecutará al menos SIEMPRE una vez. Si no quieres que se ejecute siempre, cámbialo por un `while((nuevaHierro - cantHierro) > 10){/*tu código aquí*/`. Así cuando la condición no se cumple ya no entrará ni a la primera vuelta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estas utilizando la estructura `DO-WHILE` esto quiere decir que el proceso se ejecuta la primera vez y después evaluará la condición para repetir el código, lo que necitas es la estructura `WHILE` la cual evalúa primero la condición para determinar si se debe ejecuta el código, la modificación mas simple seria esta:

```
while((nuevaHierro - cantHierro) > 10) {
    System.out.println("Vuelva a introducir la cantidad de hierro");
    System.out.println("Nueva cantidad de hierro: ");
    nuevaHierro = scan.nextInt();
    paciente1.setUltimoHierro(nuevaHierro);
}
```

Comment: Siii es ciertoa funciona bien, muchas gracias^^ error de principiante

Comment: @FranyxD que bueno poder ayudarte, el equivocarnos y aprender es parte del proceso aun entre los que tienen mucha experiencia.